# R Shiny export Code and results

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to use Shiny and feel comfortable in most. However, I want to show my code and some results(NOT the plot) on the website. I have tried:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("regression_code") 
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{
  output$regression_code <- renderPrint(
    lm<-lm(playoff$MIN.~playoff$PPG),
    summary(lm)
  )
}
```

where playoff is a data.frame.

But I can not see any result on my website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had a couple of mistakes

so run this instead and it will work. I used the mtcars because I have no access to your data set

```
ui.R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("regression_code"),
  p("model <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~mtcars$cyl)
    summary(model)")

  )
)

server.R
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$regression_code <- renderPrint({

    model <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~mtcars$cyl)
    summary(model)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much! But I can only see the results of these code, may I see the code itself?

Comment: while since your code is not changing you could just add as simple text in the main panel

Comment: I just modified a bit the ui.R so you can see the code. you can replace/test p by h4 or h3. don't forget to accept the answer